# resultset ordering of two joins

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am learning Database,hence have a very simple database of 3 tables,`Teacher`,`Student`,`Course`

**Target:** to get teacher name along with course name, he is teaching ( however i have put * in my query to check whats actually happening)

**My Query:**

```
select * from Teacher t left join Teacher_Course tc 
on t.Id =tc.Teacher_Id left join Course c on  tc.Course_Code =c.Course_Code ;
```

**My problem** is the result of my query with single join has very simple ordering as shown in figure below;

```
select * from Teacher t left join Teacher_Course tc 
    on t.Id =tc.Teacher_Id
```

[image: Single Join Query]

however when I apply the full query the resultset ordering is not understandable to me,(shown in fig below) as how it takes rows from left and compare it with joining table;

[image: Full query]
Any direction to understand this is very helpful

Comment: Removed sql server tag as this is clearly mysql.

Comment: If you want your results in a specific order you MUST add an order by to your query.

Comment: @SeanLange so without using Order by clause we cannot predict the resultset????

Comment: The resultset will be the same regardless of the ORDER BY, however, the 'order' that the resultset is presented depends on the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an ORDER BY clause to the end of your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Teacher t
LEFT JOIN Teacher_Course tc on t.Id=tc.TeacherId
LEFT JOIN Course c on tc.Course_Code=c.Course_Code
ORDER BY t.Id, tc.Course_Code_Id
```

Comment: thats nice, thanks, bt i need to ask does there exist any logic if there is no order by keyword

Comment: Without an ORDER BY clause, the DB will return the result set in no guaranteed order.  When there are multiple JOINS in the query, the DB engine connects the tables together in the most efficient manner for its own internal use.

Answer (score 1):

In most RDBMS, the order of a result set is not guaranteed unless you use an Order By clause.

Without an Order By clause, the results are generally returned in the order of the last index accessed to accomplish the query.  That order may change depending on changes to the query or changes to the data.

you must use an ORDER BY clause to guarantee the results.  And so you know, SQL Server generally ignores the Order by clause when used with TOP 100 PERCENT.

Comment: " generally returned in the order of the last index accessed to accomplish the query".....not clear ...can you elaborate it little